# ajax checked when input equal null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one item list and available properties check="checked". I want to check if name="name_emp[]" have value equal null then remove properties check="checked" at this line.How to accomplish this. Who can help me? thanks

code like this : `

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
    <div>
            <input name="name_emp[]" class="a" value=""/>
            <input name="age[]" class="a" value=""/>
            <input name="address_emp[]" class="a" value=""/>
            <input name="order_emp[]" class="a" value=""/>
                <input name="check_save" class="ab" type="checkbox" value="" checked="checked" onclick="return false;">
    </div>
        <div>
            <input name="name_emp[]" class="a" value=""/>
                <input name="age[]" class="a" value=""/>
                <input name="address_emp[]" class="a" value=""/>
                <input name="order_emp[]" class="a nhay" value=""/>
                <input name="check_save" class="ab" type="checkbox" value="" checked="checked" onclick="return false;"/>
        </div>
    <div>
        <input name="name_emp[]" class="a" value=""/>
        <input name="age[]" class="a" value=""/>
        <input name="address_emp[]" class="a" value=""/>
        <input name="order_emp[]" class="a" value=""/>
        <input name="check_save" class="ab" type="checkbox" value="" checked="checked" onclick="return false;">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="name_emp[]" class="a" value=""/>
        <input name="age[]" class="a" value=""/>
        <input name="address_emp[]" class="a" value=""/>
        <input name="order_emp[]" class="a nhay" value=""/>
        <input name="check_save" class="ab" type="checkbox" value="" checked="checked" onclick="return false;"/>
    </div>


</form>
```

Javascript :

```
 var myForm = document.forms.myform;
    var myControls = $(myForm).find('input[name="name_emp[]"]').filter(function () {
        if (!$.trim(this.value)) {
            $(this).siblings('.ab').prop('checked', false)
        } else {
            $(this).siblings('.ab').prop('checked', true)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on when you want it to happen the implementation might differ.
What you have now should work if you only want to check on initialization.
If you want to do this during some event then you'll need to tie it to that event.

https://jsfiddle.net/uercns7u/5/

```
var myForm = document.forms.myform;
checkboxStatusUpdate(); // check status on init
$('#validate').on('click', checkboxStatusUpdate); // check status on button click
$('input[name="name_emp[]"]').on('change', checkboxStatusUpdate); // check status on input change

function checkboxStatusUpdate () {
      $(myForm).find('input[name="name_emp[]"]').map(function() {
      if (!$.trim(this.value)) {
        $(this).siblings('.ab').prop('checked', false)
      } else {
        $(this).siblings('.ab').prop('checked', true)
      }
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uercns7u/6/ shows additional inputs added to check

Comment: if i want to test $('input[name="name_emp[]"]') and $('input[name=" age[]"]'). How are you

Comment: Cool glad it worked, can you mark it as the answer then? Thanks